# Aiogram 3 как заменить current_state

Tags: python, aiogram

Нужно присвоить state пользователю по user_id. В версии aiogram 2+ это происходило так:

```
state = dp.current_state(chat=chat_id, user=user_id)
await state.set_state(User.accepted)
```

В версии 3+ это не работает, скажите пожалуйста, как реализовать это в версии 3+